# Laravel add filter to all matching routes

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to add a filter to all similar routes that start with a pattern say '/admin' withouth having to manually add the filter hundreds of times?

eg:

```
Route::get('admin/sometehing','controller1')->before('auth');
Route::get('admin/sometehingelse','controller2')->before('auth');
Route::get('admin/sometehingelse')->before('auth');
Route::get('admin/sometehingelse')->before('auth');
x1000
```

How would I go about it if so?

Comment: Checkout [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/routing) under *Pattern Based Filters*, they have an example and used `admin/*`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Route::group();` to group routes with a prefix and also apply a filter that would apply to all routes.

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'admin', 'before' => 'auth'),function() {

Route::get('sometehing','controller1'); 
Route::get('sometehingelse','controller2');

....
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use Route Prefixing for this purposes like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
    Route::get('sometehing','controller1')->before('auth');
    Route::get('sometehingelse','controller2')->before('auth');
    Route::get('sometehingelse')->before('auth');
    Route::get('sometehingelse')->before('auth');
}
```